# PHP Array of Some Kind

Tags: php

I come across that array-looking object in a php file. Any clue what it is and how it works?

```
a:1:{i:2;a:2:{i:0;s:1:"m";i:1;s:10:"2013-02-11";}}
```

Comment: I realize your question is not a "duplicate" but the answer you're looking for is there.

Comment: How it's used - http://ideone.com/WouuEU

Comment: this is a serialized string you can convert this into array by using unserialize() function

Comment: [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/unserialize).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a serialized string. Run it through unserialize to convert it into a usable format.

Replace $string in the example below.

```
$unserialized = unserialize( $string );
```